# Running PHP file works correctly when SSH'd in but not via cron

Tags: php, linux

I am looking to see if a file exists on the server using a php file as per below by running "php check-backup"

```
if (!file_exists("../backups/$today/$hour.sql")) {
    echo "File doesn't exist";
} else {
    echo "File exists";
}
```

When I run this command on directly on the server when ssh'd in it works perfectly but when this is run as a cron job I cannot get it to find the file.

Comment: You'll need to use the full path for the file_exists. Unless you change directories in the cron statement, you may not know where it's running the script from.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you

Comment: Question: as what server and using what PATH environment variable does that script run when getting executed via a cron tab entry?

Answer (score 0):

As per Aynber's comment I checked the full path which got the script working.